# Send POST data as an array in PHP for logging in

Tags: php, post, authentication

I'm writing a webcrawler for a site where you have to login first. I've tried various suggestions on stack overflow, but no luck so far. I think the problem is the POST data is an array and I'm not initialising it properly?

The POST data:

user[email]:myusername

user[password]:mypassword

commit:SIGN IN

HTML on their site:

```
<form method="post" id="user_sign_in" action="" onsubmit="return checkForm()" accept-charset="UTF-8" _lpchecked="1"><input type="text" name="user[email]" id="user_email"><input type="password" name="user[password]" id="user_password"><input type="submit" value="SIGN IN" name="commit"></form>
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'user[email]' => 'myusername',
        'user[password]' => 'mypassword',
        'commit' => 'SIGN IN'
    )
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

echo file_get_contents("http://website.com/sign-in", false, $context);
```

Comment: Those keys look very strange. Are you really sure that is the structure of the data expected by that server? Please take the time to capture a working login request and add that information to the question here. Thanks.

Comment: Try Curl function.

Comment: They do look strange, I've added the code from their site to the question. I also tried Curl, but couldn't get it to log in as well.